# Discard all head changes and apply FETCH_HEAD on merge conflict

Tags: git

I did a `git pull origin master` and there are around 50 files that had conflicts, is it possible to apply the part of `FETCH_HEAD` and discard the part of `HEAD` automatically on all the files which had conflicts?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    | does not have to be set. If it isn't we'll try our best to guess the URL
=======
    | does not have to be set. If it isn't, we'll try our best to guess the URL
>>>>>>> FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use...

```
git checkout --theirs .
```

...to do this for all of the files in or below the current directory.